# Bizzaro Playing Cards

Tags: playing-cards

Here’s a problem a friend of mine posed to me a long time ago, that I was recently reminded of. I figured, with modern computing, there might be some way to figure it out:

Assume that there are two set of 52 cards, 13 of each of four sets. Now, for the purpose of a game, each card of the first deck becomes associated with one card in the other card such that, say, A♠ = 5♣.

The second set follows these conditions:
1.) No card may be it’s own twin
2.) No card may appear twice
3.) Four of a kind in the normal deck may not repeat suits in the second deck. 
4.) Any poker run in a normal deck (straight, flush) must be disrupted in the second.

Is there a set of cards that matches these conditions? And if so, what is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a puzzle that doesn't have anything to do with an actual game.  Try the Puzzling Stack Exchange.

Comment: Your third and fourth conditions are unclear. From the first two conditions, it seems like you are looking for a partition of the 52 cards into 26 disjoint pairs. However, last two conditions' mentions of the "second deck" make it sound more like you are looking for a bijective mapping from the 52 card deck to another 52 card deck. Basically, do you want to pair cards up and consider those pairs as a single unit, or do you want to replace each card in the first deck with another card in the second deck?

Comment: There are two decks, each of 52 cards, the pairing those of one deck to another. They are paired, not replaced. Sorry was unclear.

Comment: The Puzzling Stack Exchange is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: math.SE is probably an entirely better source than puzzling.SE - though this could easily *be* a math homework problem (in abstract algebra...)

Answer (score 2):

Note that (1) and (2) are satisfied by any [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the cards. There are probably many "mappings" that satisfy your conditions, but since all you seek is one possible answer, I propose the following solution.

For the values, map them in this way:

A -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3-> 6, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 10, 6 -> Q, 7 -> A, 8 -> 3, 9 -> 5, 10 -> 7, J -> 9, Q -> J, K -> K

Then: A234567890JQK -> 24680QA3579JK

So clearly any straight will not map to any straight. And because any 4 of a kind maps to a 4 of a kind, there won't be any suit duplication (your condition 3).

For the suits, consider some order of the suits [clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades]:

- For values A-4: map to the same suit
- For values 5-8: map to the next suit (e.g. clubs -> diamonds, spades -> clubs)
- For values 9-Q: map to the previous suit
- For K: map to the "opposite suit"

Then any flush (which consists of 5 cards of the same suit) cannot map to a flush, because you cannot obtain more than 4 cards of the same suit if you start with a flush.

Note that changing the suit of the K resolves the issue where K -> K, since it is required that no card be its own "twin".